# Hash function for a pair of long long?

Tags: c++, hash, tr1, unordered-map, hash-function

I need to map a pair of `long long` to a `double`, but I'm not sure what hash function to use. Each pair may consist of any two numbers, although in practice they will usually be numbers between `0` and about `100` (but again, that's not guaranteed).

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982522.aspx) is the `tr1::unordered_map` documentation. I started like this:

```
typedef long long Int;
typedef std::pair<Int, Int> IntPair;

struct IntPairHash {
  size_t operator(const IntPair& p) const {
    return ...; // how to hash the pair?
  }
};

struct IntPairEqual {
  bool operator(const IntPair& a, const IntPair& b) const {
    return a.first == b.first 
      && a.second == b.second;
  }
};

tr1::unordered_map<IntPair, double, IntPairHash, IntPairEqual> myMap;
```

In general, I'm never sure what hash function to use. What's a good general-purpose hash function?

Comment: Have you considered using one or more of the following general purpose hash functions: http://www.partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/index.html they are extremely fast and efficient.

Answer (score 10):

[boost::hash](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/hash.html) form functional library.

or write your own. simplest version = pair.first * max_second_value + pair.second

Answer (score 10):

The natural way to hash a pair is to combine the hashes of its components in some way. The most simple way is just with xor:

```
namespace std {
namespace tr1 {

template<typename a, typename b>
struct hash< std::pair<a, b> > {
private:
   const hash<a> ah;
   const hash<b> bh;
public:
   hash() : ah(), bh() {}
   size_t operator()(const std::pair<a, b> &p) const {
      return ah(p.first) ^ bh(p.second);
   }
};

}} // namespaces
```

Note that this hashes pairs like (1,1) or (2,2) all to zero, so you might want to use some more complex way to combine the hashes of the parts, depending on your data. Boost does something like this:

```
size_t seed = ah(p.first);
return bh(p.second) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
```

Comment: Please read boost hash.hpp more carefully.  Bost does something like this: seed = hash(first) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2); return seed ^ (hash(second) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2));

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion: Take a look at this SO post: ["I don't understand `std::tr1::unordered_map`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950/i-dont-understand-stdtr1unorderedmap).

Also, the Boost Documentation on [Equality Predicates and Hash Predicates](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/unordered/hash_equality.html) is a good place too (as well as this [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/unordered/examples/fnv1.hpp)).

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a hash based map? The general map based on a binary tree will work fine as long as the complexity guarantees it makes work for the problem you are solving.

Comment: Hmm okay, in that case, what would the Compare function that compares two IntPairs look like (the `less` function for IntPairs)?

Comment: @Frank: simplest form: (a.first < b.first) || ((a.first == b.first) && (a.second < b.second))

Comment: This one (a.first < b.first) && (a.second < b.second) would also work, right?

Comment: @Frank: They both define an ordering they are just different. I prefer '@dribeas' version it seems more logical (but slightly more expensive)

Comment: Actually, I found that std::pair already defines the operator<, so I don't need to provide my own compare object.

Comment: @Framk, @Martin: `(a.first < b.first) && (a.second < b.second)` is not an ordering. Pairs (1,0) and (0,1) are different and incomparable in this "ordering".